# Component testing showing no results on Optimization tab in Sitecore 8.2

Tags: content-testing

I have created a simple AB test for a compenent with 2 variations following the below link.
https://doc.sitecore.com/users/91/sitecore-experience-platform/en/preview-and-start-a-content-test.html

Test has been created successfully.
[image]

When I run my website, I get only original component and do not see any variations of the testing component. I also see no records are being inserted for tables in Analytics/Reporting database.

How can i achieve this? What am I doing wrong? Any ideas would be helpful.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you verify if your tests are created under /sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Test Lab node ?

Comment: Yes, I can see my test created under Test Lab node. I tried creating a goal and see whether it works. But it doesn't. I don't see any data in my Experience Analytics dashboard. Can you help me in setting up analytics to my website locally?